# Editing Symbology based off two qualitative attributes using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro

I have a map that shows the location of businesses. The underlying table also includes number of employees per company as well as industry. I know how to tweak the symbology to make my points use unique colors per type in the industry column. I also know how to vary the size of my points using graduated symbols. I cannot seem to figure out how to do both.

As a note: I know that I can take my unique colors by industry and then use "Vary symbology by attributes" to change the point sizes. However, this seems to use a continuous scale on the sizing and I want to be able to define the bin boundaries, (for instance: 0-100 employees, 100-250 employees, etc.)

I do not believe there is a way to do this in the GUI, though if there is, great! I know python and could write the conditionals to do this, but I am new to using python with Esri, so I am not sure how to apply things to the map with code - or even if it's possible.

Any guidance?